# Comic about space exploration team meeting human-sized, insect-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-exploration

When I was a young boy living in Russia I came across a comic book that featured a space exploration team which made contact with not so friendly aliens who resembled Earth's insects, except that they were human sized and appeared to be at least as intelligent as the humans. Please help me find this book's name.

I must have read it in the late eighties or early nineties so I might be very foggy or downright wrong about some of the details.

More things that I remember

- Early on there was a panel showing a human admiring ants crawling through an ant farm.
- I remember one of the humans using suction cups to scale a tall building or spacecraft.
- The aliens appeared to wear some sort of clothing
- One of the main aliens looked like an ant standing upright on its hind legs and had at least two pairs of arms.

Comment: Think this might be a classic Russian story. I think even one of the first Russian(?) movies (b/w) predating the Apollo program showed a team landing on the moon and meeting some kind of ant people there.

Comment: Sort of like a sophisticated version of the Starship Troopers film franchise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a classic Polish comic book called "Walka o planetę" (The Battle for The Planet) written by Arnold Mostowicz and Alfred Górny and illustrated by Bogusław Polch. It was part of "[Bogowie z Kosmosu](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogowie_z_kosmosu)" (Gods from the Space) comic cycle published in 80s. The whole series has sold millions of copies in 12 languages, including Russian.

The cycle tells the story inspired by [Erich von Däniken's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_von_D%C3%A4niken) hyptohesis of "ancient aliens". In mentioned book, the protagonists (human-looking aliens from planet Des) fight against insect-like alien race which want to take over Earth.

> - I remember one of the humans using suction cups to scale a tall building or spacecraft.

You got it right:

[image]

> - The aliens appeared to wear some soft of clothing
> - One of the main
>     aliens looked like an ant standing upright on its hind legs and had at
>     least two pairs of arms.

Yes, the insectoid aliens looked exactly like this:

[image]

> - Early on there was a panel showing a human admiring ants crawling
>     through an ant farm.

You probably mean panel showing alien planet, which was heavily overpopulated:

[image]